# Make a Menu using Match Case Python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, menu, switch-statement

I have created another MENU in a different exercise using **IF** in this time I did it with **MATCH CASE** and I have a doubt, is it possible to print the menu again and if it is possible how I would do it, I think in an if but it is the first time that I use these sentences.

this is my code:
...Later i need to work with dictionaries so with this method can do it?, or I need to use IF to create the menu from the beginning?

```
menu = """
1. Datos del pasajero.
2. Agrega una ciudad. 
3. Ingresa DNI para ver las ciudades que coinciden con el dato.
4. Escribe una ciudad para ver el # de pasajeros.
5. Ingresa DNI para ver los paises que coinciden con el dato.
6. Ingresa un pais y mostrar el total de personas que viajan.
7. Terminar el programa
"""

viajeros = {}
paises = {}

print(menu)
dato_leido = int(input('Escriba una opcion para comenzar con el programa: '))

match dato_leido:
    
    case 1:
        print('Escriba los datos del pasajero: ')

    case 2:
        print('Agrega una ciudad a la lista:')

    case 3:
        print('Ingresa el DNI del pasajero para ver a que ciudad ha viajado: ')    

    case 4:
        print('Ingrese una ciudad para ver el numero de pasajeros: ')   

    case 5:
        print('Ingresa el DNI de una persona para ver a que paises viaja: ')

    case 6:
        print('Ingresa un pais y mostrar el total de personas que viajan: ')

    case _:
        print('Saliendo del programa en 3, 2, 1(FIN).')
```

Comment: _is it possible to print the menu again_ Of course.  Just call `print(menu)` again.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: check that aswer and that is not the solution like you say that way is simple but dont solve my problem

Comment: If it doesn't solve your problem, then you need to say clearly what your problem really is.  You asked to "print the menu again", and I told you how to do that.